# Asynchronous Promise and then()

Tags: firefox, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I was going through the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension.
I could not understand the keyword then() in the choose_beast.js script. I know it is something related to promises in javascript. Can you explain in simple language promises and use of then in this context?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I already have read it but could not understand in simple terms.

Comment: Related: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 1):

Let us compare synchronous and asynchronous code.

Looking at a normal synchronous code:

```
let a = Date.now();
let b = a * 3;
```

`a` is set before `b` is set and it is available for the next line to be used

Looking at an asynchronous code:

```
let a = someAsyncFuntion();
let b = a * 3; // runs into error
```

`a` is NOT set before `b` is set and it is NOT available for the next line to be used, therefore it results in error.

The `someAsyncFuntion()` is queued to run when the next process is available. The parser moves to `let b = a * 3;` but here the `a` is not set yet, so there would be an error.

I simple words, in Promise the function is queued to run asynchronously. Therefore, `then()` is when it has done it.

Looking at the example on above page:

```
var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}); 
gettingActiveTab.then((tabs) => { browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {beastURL: chosenBeastURL}); });
```

`browser.tabs.query()` does not run immediately and does not get results immediately. Therefore, we write the code so that when it gets the result `then()` do something.

```
// query tabs asynchronously
var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({.....});

// once got the result THEN do something 
gettingActiveTab.then( /* do something */ );
```

I hope that helps.